# Como guardar nuevo archivo con Visual Basic en Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Actualmenten estoy tomando los valores de una hoja, en bloque de 200 registros. Pero lo que busco es guardar cada rango de registros en un archivo nuevo y en una ruta especificada.

```
Worksheets(Index + 1).Select
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, j As Range, num As Integer, num2 As Integer, total_reg As Integer, val As Integer
va = 1
total_reg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
num = 202
Set r1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:N1")
Do While num < total_reg + 1
   num2 = num + 199
   Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & num & ":N" & num2)
   Set j = Union(r1, r2)
   j.Copy
   Workbooks.Add
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Windows("IMPORTAR-EXPORTAR.xlsm").Activate
   Worksheets(Index + 1).Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   ActiveSheet.Range("G11").Select
   num = num + 200
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\nuevo\Book" & val & ".xlsx"
   val = val + 1
Loop
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me sale un error. donde podria editar?

Comment: Por favor, editta tu pregunta y añade el mensaje completo de error que te sale.

Answer (score 0):

tu línea de código `Windows("IMPORTAR-EXPORTAR.xlsm").Activate` hace que el libro activo (`ActiveWorkbook`) sea un archivo XLSM, es decir, un libro habilitado para macros.

luego haces `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\nuevo\Book" & val & ".xlsx"`

Y te da error porque en tiempo de ejecución no puedes guardar un XLSM que está ejecutando una macro como XLSX.

Además, un consejo, `val` es una palabra reservada del sistema.

> [Función
> Val](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function)

Te recomiendo que como nombre de parámetro/variable, utilices otra cosa como `MiVal`, `EsteVal`, `_Val_` o algo así. Usar como variables palabras reservadas del sistema puede producir resultados inesperados y corrupciones de archivo a largo plazo.

respecto a tu código, creo que primero deberías salvar donde pegas lo que copias, y luego ya activar tu libro.

Algo así:

```
'
'
'
'resto de tu código
'
'
'
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\nuevo\Book" & val & ".xlsx"
Windows("IMPORTAR-EXPORTAR.xlsm").Activate

'
'
'
'resto de tu código
'
'
'
```